# Segmentation fault in javascript with persistent function

Tags: javascript, c++, node.js

Dynamic library is created using some C files. This dynamic library is used by a C++ function. One of the C-functions calls a C++ function. Which in turn will invoke a Javascript Function Callback. I am getting segmentation fault in C++ function.

Here is the code, 
In test.h,

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
      void cppFunc(void);
#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

Here is the code in test.c

```
#include "test.h"
void cFunc(void){
/* some code */
    cppFunc();
}
```

Here is the code in test.cpp

```
#include "test.h"
static Nan::Persistent<v8::Function> callback;
void storeFunc(const v8::FunctionCallbackInfo<v8::Value>& args){
    if(args[0]->IsFunction()){
         Local<Function> cb = Local<Function>::Cast(args[0]);
         callback.Reset(cb);
    } 
}
void cppFunc(void){
    Isolate *isolate = Isolate::GetCurrent();
    Local<Function> c_back = Local<Function>::New(isolate, callback);
    Nan::MakeCallback(Nan::GetCurrentContext()->Global(), c_back, 0, {});
}
void init(Handle<Object> exports, Handle<Object> module)
{
NODE_SET_METHOD(exports, "FuncStore", storeFunc);
}
NODE_MODULE(test, init)
```

test.node is created by using "node-gyp configure build" command. No errors or warnings are shown.

Following is my test.js file,

```
var sample = require("./build/Release/test.node");
sample.FuncStore(function(){
    console.log("Callback has been called!!");
});
```

On executing test.js by "node test.js", a segmentation fault occurs when  cFunc() calls cppFunc(). Segmentation fault is happening exactly at the line "Local c_back = Local::New(isolate, callback);" in cppFunc().

What could be the reason?

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is that the pointer "isolate" is `NULL`. Accessing a pointer with no value or an invalid value can cause a segmentation fault. You should check for it's existence by performing:

```
Isolate *isolate = Isolate::GetCurrent();

if (isolate) {
  //it is now safe to use isolate
  Local<Function> c_back = Local<Function>::New(isolate, callback);
  Nan::MakeCallback(Nan::GetCurrentContext()->Global(), c_back, 0, {});
}
else {
  //possibly generate your own warning here
}
```

As a side note, it seems Isolate::GetCurrent is deprecated https://github.com/nodejs/node/commit/409d413363

Comment: Tried this and seems like "isolate" has been assigned NULL when the call for cppFunc() is coming from cFunc(). 
While if a CPP-function is created, which calls a C-Function, which in turn calls cppFunc() then isolate is not assigned with a NULL value. This behavior is a bit confusing to me.
Ex: In test.c File
void testFunc()
{
     cppFunc();
}

In test.cpp 
void newFunc()
{
     testFunc();
} 

And call newFunc() from javascript in similar way as in original question.

Comment: Then we have found the source of your problem which is what you were asking for. Your isolate pointer is not being properly initialized.

Comment: Any way to get it properly initialized?

Comment: You may need to show more if your code. I cannot tell where and when cFunc or cppFunc are being invoked.

Comment: I am basically trying to use this code in node-red for a custom radio frequency module. When ever the radio frequency module receives some data, this cFunc() will be called. cFunc() is nothing but a receive callback at C level. Is this information enough or more is needed?

Comment: Well the part I'm confused about is you say that cFunc calls cppFunc. Since node.js add-one are written using the v8 C++ API, why do you need have a C function call back a C++ function? And since you say you have no problem initializing isolate when using the C++ function, why not just have it call the C++ function directly?

Comment: The radio frequency module has its own software stack running to handle transmit and receive operations. This software stack is written in C. So when ever some data is received, that data can be accessed only via the c-callback, which in other words is cFunc(). So cFunc() has the data that i need now, so I was hoping to pass this data onto C++  and then onto node-js. This Receive callback cFunc() is an interrupt based function. Once the data is received completely the RF-stack generates a software interrupt and calls cFunc().